# Issue Disabling certain option fields from a select dropdown using Javascript

Tags: javascript, select, drop-down-menu

Am working on an application whereby I have some cards that have select dropdown fields. On the Cards I have written a JavaScript logic whereby if the user selected a wife as an option on the 1st Card select drop down, the 2nd drop down wife field disables which is fine.

The problem is on the 3rd card it does not disable. Basically I want when the user **selects wife option on the 1st card, all other wife options on other cards should de disabled instantly**

**Markup Code**

```
<!-- Card 1 -->
    **<form method="POST" action="#" id="phase3">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <!-- Gender -->
            <div class="row registerRelationph3">
                <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
                <select class="fm-input firstMenu" id="relation1" required>
                    <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
                    <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
                    <option value="Son"> Son </option>
                    <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <!-- END -->

            <!-- DOb -->
            <div class="row">
            <label class="fm-input" style="font-size: 10px;"> Date Of Birth :</label>
            <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
            </div>
            <!-- END dob -->
             <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"> Save Details <i class="fa fa-check-circle" ></i></button>
    </form>
    <!-- End card 1 -->

    <!-- Card 2-->
    <form method="POST" action="#" id="phase3">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <!-- Gender -->
            <div class="row registerRelationph3">
                <label class="fm-input otherMenu"> Relation :</label>
                <select class="fm-input" id="relation1" required>
                    <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
                    <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
                    <option value="Son"> Son </option>
                    <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <!-- END -->

            <!-- DOb -->
            <div class="row">
                <label class="fm-input" style="font-size: 10px;"> Date Of Birth :</label>
                <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
            </div>
            <!-- END dob -->
             <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"> Save Details <i class="fa fa-check-circle" ></i></button>
    </form>
    <!-- End card 2-->

    <!-- Card 3-->
    <form method="POST" action="#" id="phase3">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <!-- Gender -->
            <div class="row registerRelationph3">
                <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
                <select class="fm-input otherMenu" id="relation1" required>
                    <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
                    <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
                    <option value="Son"> Son </option>
                    <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <!-- END -->

            <!-- DOb -->
            <div class="row">
                <label class="fm-input" style="font-size: 10px;"> Date Of Birth :</label>
                <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
            </div>
            <!-- END dob -->
             <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"> Save Details <i class="fa fa-check-circle" ></i></button>
    </form>
    <!-- End card 3-->**
```

**Javascript Code**

```
document.querySelector('.firstMenu').addEventListener('change', function () {
    document.querySelector('.otherMenu option[value="Wife"]').disabled = this.value === 'Wife';     
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things were wrong:

1. You had the `otherMenu` class on the `<label>` instead of the `<select>` for the second card
2. You need to use `querySelectorAll()` and iterate the element collection. `querySelector()` will only select the first matching element.

```js
document.querySelector('.firstMenu').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var selectedOption = this.value;
  var otherSelectOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.otherMenu option');
  otherSelectOptions.forEach(function(option) {
    option.disabled = option.value === selectedOption;
  });

});
```

```html
<!-- Card 1 -->
<form method="POST" action="#" id="phase3">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <!-- Gender -->
  <div class="row registerRelationph3">
    <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
    <select class="fm-input firstMenu" id="relation1" required>
      <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
      <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
      <option value="Son"> Son </option>
      <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- END -->

  <!-- DOb -->
  <div class="row">
    <label class="fm-input" style="font-size: 10px;"> Date Of Birth :</label>
    <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
  </div>
  <!-- END dob -->
  <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"> Save Details <i class="fa fa-check-circle" ></i></button>
</form>
<!-- End card 1 -->

<!-- Card 2-->
<form method="POST" action="#" id="phase3">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <!-- Gender -->
  <div class="row registerRelationph3">
    <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
    <select class="fm-input otherMenu" id="relation1" required>
      <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
      <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
      <option value="Son"> Son </option>
      <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- END -->

  <!-- DOb -->
  <div class="row">
    <label class="fm-input" style="font-size: 10px;"> Date Of Birth :</label>
    <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
  </div>
  <!-- END dob -->
  <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"> Save Details <i class="fa fa-check-circle" ></i></button>
</form>
<!-- End card 2-->

<!-- Card 3-->
<form method="POST" action="#" id="phase3">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <!-- Gender -->
  <div class="row registerRelationph3">
    <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
    <select class="fm-input otherMenu" id="relation1" required>
      <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
      <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
      <option value="Son"> Son </option>
      <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- END -->

  <!-- DOb -->
  <div class="row">
    <label class="fm-input" style="font-size: 10px;"> Date Of Birth :</label>
    <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
  </div>
  <!-- END dob -->
  <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit"> Save Details <i class="fa fa-check-circle" ></i></button>
</form>
<!-- End card 3-->
```

Comment: Thanks alot it works fine,, Can I use the same code to disable for both husband and wife,, Basically when the user selects husband, all other husband options are disabled, when the user selects wife, all other wife options are disabled..

Comment: I guess you want this to work for "Son" and "Daughter", too? I edited the answer to reflect that. You just need to remove the value attribute from the selector in order to iterate over all options and compare the selected value against the option values in order to decide whether to disable them or not.